# Unable to render a template after using fetch in django

Tags: python, django, fetch

I have the following requirement:

- Send data to backend using `fetch()`
- receive the data in a view and render another template ( route to a different view)

The following is my code snippet:

JS:

```
fetch("/addpost", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ value: selecteddict }),

    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json;",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.text();
    })
    .then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    });

// the data is being sent successfully
```

Django View1:

```
@csrf_exempt
def addpost(request):
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        song = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))['value']
        print(song)
        # I want to redirect to another view called createpost that renders a new page
        return JsonResponse({'status':201})

    return render(request, 'addpost.html')
```

Django createpost view:

```
def createpost(request):
    return render(request, 'createpost.html')
```

The view `createpost` is working fine when given the required path but it is not rendering when it's redirected from `addpost`

Please suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your addpost view returns as JsonResponse in case of a POST request. If you want to redirect somewhere you need to use redirect() instead of JsonResponse()

Comment: I tried using redirect. I get : GET /createpost HTTP/1.1" 200 1864 in the logs but the page is not being rendered

Comment: please show your urls.py and the redirect(...)  you used.

Comment: `return redirect(createpost)`
` path('createpost', views.createpost, name='createpost'),`

Comment: redirect('createpost') .... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: I am still getting "GET /createpost HTTP/1.1" 200 1864. is it possible that the fetch() is waiting for a response

Comment: I tested your code - it works. I suppose you are aware of that your fetch result will only be printed in the console of your browser not be shown as new page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232942/discussion-between-ag2byte-and-razenstein).